# SSD, HDD, lvm on luks, btrfs, efi

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, btrfs, luks

I want to install Ubuntu desktop 20.04 on my laptop (which has an SSD and an HDD) using this scheme:

1. Create luks2 container on each drive and lvms inside them.
2. Format ssd's lvm as btrfs for using as root.
3. Format HDD's lvm as xfs for using as /home.
4. Do i need to create separated /boot instead of ESP? Now grub supports luks2

Do i need use sub volume? Should I use btrfs mount option (-o subvolume=@, @/home) for root and home?

Comment: What would the default Ubuntu installer do?